# Raspbery Pi - Looping video omxplayer

Tags: shell, video, raspberry-pi

I have been working on a project to play all videos in a folder. It works just fine, but I need the video path to change based on input that change periodically with CRON. I want it to change the video path as soon as the input change, but not until the current video ended, but without playing the rest of the video in the current video path.

Here is the code to play all video in the folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

# get rid of the cursor so we don't see it when videos are running
setterm -cursor off

# set here the path to the directory containing your videos
VIDEOPATH="/mnt/storage/videos" 

# you can normally leave this alone
SERVICE="omxplayer"

for entry in $VIDEOPATH/*
    do
        clear
    $SERVICE $entry > /dev/null

    while ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    do
        sleep 5;
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the for loop in a function and call it recursively if the input has changed. You don't need the while loop since the script will only continue once omxplayer has finished playing a video

```
#!/bin/sh

VIDEOPATH="/mnt/storage/videos"
SERVICE="omxplayer"

function playvideos {

  for entry in $1/*
  do
    clear
    $2 $entry > /dev/null

    if [ $input_has_changed ]
    then
      # get new video path here
      playvideos $NEW_VIDEO_PATH $2
      break
    fi
  done
}

playvideos $VIDEOPATH $SERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late question but this is the best solution without the in-between video gap.

```
#!/bin/sh
while : ;
do for f in /var/www/html/led/autoplayv/*.mp4;
do omxplayer -n -l "$f";
done;
done
```